# Generating all combinations containing at least one element of a given set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I use `combnk` to generate a list of combinations. How can I generate a subset of combinations, which always includes particular values. For example, for `combnk(1:10, 2)` I only need combinations which contain 3 and/or 5. Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: If you aren't too limited by performance, you could just brute-force it, i.e. create a large number of combinations and then only selecting the good ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, in your specific example, choosing two integers from the set {1, ..., 10} such that one of the chosen integers is 3 or 5 yields 9+9-1 = 17 known combinations, so you can just enumerate them.

In general, to find all of the n-choose-k combinations from integers {1, ..., n} that contain integer m, that is the same as finding the (n-1)-choose-(k-1) combinations from integers {1, ..., m-1, m+1, ..., n}.

In matlab, that would be

```
combnk([1:m-1 m+1:n], k-1)
```

(This code is still valid even if `m` is 1 or n.)

Answer (score 2):

For a brute force solution, you can generate all your combinations with [COMBNK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/combnk.html) then use the functions [ANY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/any.html) and [ISMEMBER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ismember.html) to find only those combinations that contain one or more of a subset of numbers. Here's how you can do it using your above example:

```
v = 1:10;            %# Set of elements
vSub = [3 5];        %# Required elements (i.e. at least one must appear in the
                     %#   combinations that are generated)
c = combnk(v,2);     %# Find pairwise combinations of the numbers 1 through 10
rowIndex = any(ismember(c,vSub),2);  %# Get row indices where 3 and/or 5 appear
c = c(rowIndex,:);   %# Keep only combinations with 3 and/or 5
```

---

**EDIT:**

For a more elegant solution, it looks like [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014071/generating-combinations-in-matlab/4015751#4015751) and I had a similar idea. However, I've generalized the solution so that it works for both an arbitrary number of required elements and for repeated elements in `v`. The function SUBCOMBNK will find all the combinations of `k` values taken from a set `v` that include at least one of the values in the set `vSub`:

```
function c = subcombnk(v,vSub,k)
%#SUBCOMBNK   All combinations of the N elements in V taken K at a time and
%#   with one or more of the elements in VSUB as members.

  %# Error-checking (minimal):

  if ~all(ismember(vSub,v))
    error('The values in vSub must also be in v.');
  end

  %# Initializations:

  index = ismember(v,vSub);  %# Index of elements in v that are in vSub
  vSub = v(index);           %# Get elements in v that are in vSub
  v = v(~index);             %# Get elements in v that are not in vSub
  nSubset = numel(vSub);     %# Number of elements in vSub
  nElements = numel(v);      %# Number of elements in v
  c = [];                    %# Initialize combinations to empty

  %# Find combinations:

  for kSub = max(1,k-nElements):min(k,nSubset)
    M1 = combnk(vSub,kSub);
    if kSub == k
      c = [c; M1];
    else
      M2 = combnk(v,k-kSub);
      c = [c; kron(M1,ones(size(M2,1),1)) repmat(M2,size(M1,1),1)];
    end
  end

end
```

You can test this function against the brute force solution above to see that it returns the same output:

```
cSub = subcombnk(v,vSub,2);
setxor(c,sort(cSub,2),'rows')   %# Returns an empty matrix if c and cSub
                                %#   contain exactly the same rows
```

I further tested this function against the brute force solution using `v = 1:15;` and `vSub = [3 5];` for values of `N` ranging from 2 to 15. The combinations created were identical, but SUBCOMBNK was significantly faster as shown by the average run times (in msec) displayed below:

```
N  | brute force | SUBCOMBNK
---+-------------+----------
2  |     1.49    |    0.98
3  |     4.91    |    1.17
4  |    17.67    |    4.67
5  |    22.35    |    8.67
6  |    30.71    |   11.71
7  |    36.80    |   14.46
8  |    35.41    |   16.69
9  |    31.85    |   16.71
10 |    25.03    |   12.56
11 |    19.62    |    9.46
12 |    16.14    |    7.30
13 |    14.32    |    4.32
14 |     0.14    |    0.59*   #This could probably be sped up by checking for
15 |     0.11    |    0.33*   #simplified cases (i.e. all elements in v used)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to improve Steve's answer : in your case (you want all combinations with 3 **and/or** 5) it will be

- all k-1/n-2 combinations with 3 added
- all k-1/n-2 combinations with 5 added
- all k-2/n-2 combinations with 3 and 5 added

Easily generalized for any other case of this type.