# How to create a list of all possible groupings from N elements

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Suppose I have N elements, I want to create a list of all possible groupings of the elements, where there can be multiple groups of the N elements at once.

For example, suppose we have 4 elements: a, b, c, d. Let [ ] denote that the elements within the brackets are in a grouping. I'm looking for an algorithm (in Matlab if possible) that can create a list of all the ways they can group together like so:

- a b c d
- [a b] c d
- a [b c] d
- a b [c d]
- [a d] b c
- [a c] b d
- a c [b d]
- [a b] [c d]
- [b c] [a d]
- [a c] [b d]
- [a b c] d
- a [b c d]
- b [c d a]
- c [d a b]
- [a b c d]

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp! Since this question (as far as I can tell) does not require any computational or scientific background to answer, you will get a better answer at StackOverflow. I'll flag for migration, so you don't have to double post.

Comment: The trick is to use recursion.  Suppose your function f() is passed a set X of elements, and you want it to return all ways to break X into groups as a list of lists.  Take the first element in X and call it h, and call the rest of X R.  If you knew how to find all ways to break R into groups, you could, for each way w, try adding h to each of the groups in w, and leaving it as a separate singleton group...  and you do know how to find all those ways, using f(R) :)  All you need to do is handle the base case, where X contains a single element.

Comment: There are numerous questions/answers on this site (mark duplicates people!!) that tackle this problem. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014071/generating-combinations-in-matlab) is a better duplicate. Check out [`allcomb`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10064-allcomb) on the MathWorks FileExchange or put `combnk` in a loop.

Comment: @horchler: I'm sure this question has been asked (probably many times) before, but the question you link to is different.  There are many more ways of grouping (what Ivan wants) than combinations (what your link talks about, and equivalent to "ways of grouping into exactly 2 groups").

Answer (score 0):

This solution generates all possibilities:

```
%Generate potential solutions
p=dec2base(0:base2dec('123',4), 4);
%convert to numeric
p=[zeros(size(p,1),1) p-'0'];
for col=2:4
    %sort out. in column col a new group index is used, but not all previous indices are used.
    valid=max(p(:,1:col-1),[],2)+1>=p(:,col);
    p=p(valid,:);
end
```

The output is a matrix which labels the characters. For example `1233` is `ab[cd]` in your notation.