# How to have indices of an array, except the elements, when we use n-choose-k?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matlab, increment, indices

I would like to write an algorithm which gives an integer, and also an array, as input, and increases some elements. Assume that our array has 4 elements. Indices of selected elements which are going to be increased are as following (left hand integers are our algorithm input and right hand ones are the selected indices):

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3
4 -> 4
5 -> 1,2
6 -> 1,3
7 -> 1,4
8 -> 2,3
9 -> 2,4
10 -> 3,4
11 -> 1,2,3
12 -> 1,2,4
13 -> 1,3,4
14 -> 2,3,4
15 -> 1,2,3,4
```

Anyone knows how can I implement this algorithm in MATLAB?

Comment: The question is totally unclear, but intuitively it reminds me of a binary representation...

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, but I just can't declare my question better. It's just like a clock. Moving the first pointer to the end(second), would produce another pointer(minute), and so on .

Comment: I must agree with Eugene Sh.  I cannot see the pattern, but really, it's not a Matlab specific question.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like rather simple problem, but your wording is awful. Which pointers? Which array? How the input 5 related to output 1,2 ?

Comment: @macduff Actually it has an pattern. Assume that you want to select at least 1 object from 4 objects. You can select just one of them, in 4 ways. You can select 2 of them, in 6 ways. You can select 3 of them, in 4 ways. Or finally, you can select all of them, in 1 way. sum of these ways, are 15 ways which exist in my question above.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I know there is no pointer in matlab, but just imagine that we have some pointers. Assume that first pointer moves from first element to the end. By arriving the first pointer to the end, a new pointer would be placed on the first element, and the previous pointer would move from second element to the end(this is how 5 movement of a pointer would result in output 1,2).

Comment: Ok, now I am starting to understand. You are trying to enumerate different choices out of N elements in a specific way. It is not hard, I will write a way to do it when I have time, if no one will do it before

Comment: @EugeneSh. I just couldn't find proper words :D Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this does look like we are choosing unique combinations of objects starting from one object, up to four objects.  We are simply enumerating all choices for all possible number of objects.

Comment: Look here in the mean time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4014071/generating-combinations-in-matlab

Comment: @EugeneSh. It was not helpful. I need to increase my array elements, in place! so I need exact the indices, not the elements.

Comment: The elements ARE your indices, as far as I understand.

Comment: Do you need the results in precisely that order? Or do you just need to enumerate all combinations (possibly in a different order)?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sorry, You are right. The elements could be the indices. thx.

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, I need to keep the precise order.

Comment: And do you want to generate all results at once? Can you store them all in memory  at the same time?

Comment: No, I prefer to have one at a time. calculating all of them would not be necessary.

Comment: I've decided to put the final vote in closing the question.  Judging from the attempts and multiple inquiries to try to answer your problem, yet no one being able to answer you in what you deem adequate, it seems that you need to add more information to your question and improve its quality by being more explicit in what you desire.  This way, no one else wastes time in attempting to answer with the risk of not performing what you're looking for.  Please be more explicit in your instructions and I will opt to reopen the question.

Comment: @rayryeng In a sense, the user CapeCode's answer was helpful to me. I can define an array which each elements of it are exact the indices. In this way, by utilizing 'nchoosek' function, I will be able to have indices which I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect by 'pointers' you mean the arrows of a clock, but that doesn't make it any clearer. What I get from your pattern is that you want the *binomial coefficients*, you can get them with the [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) function:

```
array=[1 2 3 4];
for k= 1:numel(array)
    b{k,1} = nchoosek(array,k);
end
```

Comment: Yup... this is exactly it.  +1.

Comment: That's good and helpful, but because of computational overhead, I don't want to calculate all of them (or at least, more than one of them) at the same time. I just want to obtain one of them each time. Is there any other choice?

Comment: And also, how can I increase them in my array?!

Comment: @MorTezaDM what is it that you want to increase?

Comment: @CapeCode Just the elements which are placed in the indices. Your code gives me the elements, not the indices. so I can't manipulate my array.

Comment: @MorTezaDM I'm confused, the elements *are* the indices, aren't they?

Comment: Nope! ... The elements are completely different values. I didn't mention them in my question!

Comment: But I can define an array which its elements are the indices, and by making use of your code, I can have the indices. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can't generate all combinations at once (to save memory).

If you need to enumerate all combinations (so that each combination appears once) but *you don't mind the order*, you can:

1. Increase a counter from `1` to `2^n-1`, where `n` is the number of elements
2. Obtain the binary representation of the counter
3. Find digits equal to one in that representation.

Code:

```
n = 4;
for counter = 1:2^n-1
    comb = find((fliplr(dec2bin(counter,n))=='1'));
    disp([num2str(counter) ' -> ' num2str(comb)]);
end
```

Result:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 1  2
4 -> 3
5 -> 1  3
6 -> 2  3
7 -> 1  2  3
8 -> 4
9 -> 1  4
10 -> 2  4
11 -> 1  2  4
12 -> 3  4
13 -> 1  3  4
14 -> 2  3  4
15 -> 1  2  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to preserve the order of selection related to the input integer, in the way I mentioned in my question.